# Spring Validation not working on Service Layer level

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation

I have a Spring Boot project ( 2.3.3 ) where I want to validate the service layer methods input parameters. So in my pom.xml I added

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

as it is no more part of the parent. Next I have my service method interface and the implementing service method. My implemening service is annotated with @Validated and my method looks like

```
public void deleteGreetingById(@NotNull(message = "greetingId must not be null.")Integer greetingId) {
```

I've also read that the validation is bound per default only to the controller layer. So to enable it also for the servie layer I added a PostValidationProcesser.

```
@Configuration
public class MethodValidationConfig {

    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
        return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

When I now execute my test with null as input param, nothing happens and no exception is thrown. When I do

```
 Assert.notNull(greetingId,"greetingId must not be null");
```

inside the method, an InvalidParameterException is thrown like expected. But I would prefere the annotation based validation because of the @Valid validation of whole class Objects as input parameter.

Can one explain why the validation is not triggered?

**EDIT:**

```
@RestController
public class GreetingsConsumerController {

    private final GreetingsService greetingsService;

    public GreetingsConsumerController(GreetingsService greetingsService) {
        this.greetingsService = greetingsService;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/greetings", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Greeting createGreeting( @RequestBody @Valid GreetingDto greetingDto){
        return greetingsService.addGreeting(greetingDto);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/greetings/{id}")
    public Greeting getGreetingById(@PathVariable Integer id){
        return greetingsService.findGreetingById(id);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/greetings")
    public List<Greeting> getAllGreetings(){
        return greetingsService.findAllGreetings();
    }

    @DeleteMapping(value = "/greetings/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void deleteGreetingById(@PathVariable Integer id){

        greetingsService.deleteGreetingById(id);
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface GreetingsService {
    
        Greeting findGreetingById(Integer greetingId);
        List<Greeting> findAllGreetings();
        Greeting addGreeting( GreetingDto greetingDto);
        void deleteGreetingById( Integer greetingId);
    
    }
```

IterfaceImpl:

```
@Service
@Validated
public class GreetingsServiceImpl implements GreetingsService {

.
.
.
       @Override
        public void deleteGreetingById(@NotNull(message = "greetingId must not be null. ") Integer greetingId) {
            ...
        }

}
```

I also added the Bean to my SpringBootApplication but still no exception is thrown.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class GreetingsConsumerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(GreetingsConsumerApplication.class, args
        );
    }
    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
        return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you call the method? And how does the class look like where you added the NotNull constraint?

Comment: I call the method like every general method. The NotNull in my example is related to a single parameter ( as you can see in my example the param is greetingId). My Class constraints validation is working as expected for Controller Input Dtos. I just does not work when I try to validate params in the service layer.

Comment: You are using Spring Boot is this `MethodValidationConfig` picked up by Spring Boot? How are you calling that `deleteGreetingById` method? If that is called from within the same class it won't work.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have a rest endpoint where I receive the request. Then I extract the id and call the Method via the interface Instance. I don't actually know if this MethodvalidationConfig is picked. I'll try to seta breakpoint. I got this solution from the example here https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation-method-constraints

Comment: It needs to be in a package covered by Spring Boot else you need to import it (or just add the `@Bean` method to your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class, which is probably easier).

Comment: @M.Deinum I updated my question

Comment: Do you have the proper annotations (the correct `@NotNull` as there are several) and is there a javax.validation implementation on the classpath (normally `hibernate-validator` is included in `spring-boot-starter-validation`.

Comment: the import is javax.validation.constraints.NotNull

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample example to validate a model at service layer.

```
class   TestModel{
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    }

TestModel model= new TestModel();
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<TestModel>> violations = validator.validate(model);
```

Comment: My model validation works when the request hits the controller. Why is it necessary to create a separate validator? I think it should work same way like in the controller level?

Comment: As per my knowledge it does not work at service layer, we need to write separate validator for this.

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" the problem. My error was that I configured my Tests wrong. I configured the test with

`@Extendwith(SpringExtension.class)`

as I've only written unit tests without using the context in this class before. Obviously using the parameter validation this way you have to use the Context which makes the whole scenario an integration test. I'm glad it works now and I'm sorry for the needless discussions. I should have posted my test also in the code.

Although I am glad it works now I'm also a bit confused. In genereal I don't want to start the Spring context just for constraint validation. But this is another question.

Answer (score -1):

When you have services implementing interfaces and you reference the interface you need the validation annotations on the interface, not the implementing class. Add the validation annotations to the GreetingsService interface.

Comment: I added it on also on the interface and on both. Nothing happens

Comment: Did you also add the @Validated annotation to the interface?

Comment: Yes I tried it on the Interface, the Service and on both.

Comment: For my Boot 2.3 applications I don't need to create the MethodValidationPostProcessor bean as you do and method validation works. For straight up Spring applications I create the method validation post processor and set its validator factory to a LocalValidatorFactoryBean.

Comment: I tried it without thisprocessor but nothing changed. The method is still executed with the null object and no exception is thrown